# find file names with zipinfo command for nested zip without extracting zip

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to find file names in a nested zip with following command without extracting the main zip file.

It is listing first level but not listing nested zip contents.  Any suggestion ?

```
find . -type f -newermt '02/01/2021 0:00:00' -exec zipinfo {} \;
```